# Is this polygon pour, how much current can it carry?

Tags: current, current-source, copper-pour, polygon

On my attached picture, I draw battery pins, (red square) component that want to current, (blue square, a component want to about 4-6 ampere) and way of current (black line).

I have a some questions. This picture is a example for my question.
I'm wondering this polygon pour(copper area) really can carry about 20 to 30 amperes?

Second question is, really do a component reach to wanted current from this polygon pour?

If I use a trace, of course I can known can trace carry to wanted current or cant. Because ı can calculate trace width and ı learned how much can carry current.

[image]

Comment: So you want to know if your plane can carry that much current? It will be fine with 4-6A. But 20-30A might be a bit too much at the red square where all the current gathers. I tend to use two layers for something like that. Can the battery pins 20-handle 30A?

Comment: Thank u for your comment. The  real circuit is more complex from this Picture. I have a different battery layer also there are 4 or 5 extra pin for current. I'm wondering only how can be sure a component really to feed enough from battery pins.

Answer (score 1):

If your pour is wider than the trace you'd need to use to achieve your desired maximum resistance, then the polygon itself will not be what limits your current.

If you really want to know the effect of the polygon geometry, you can do a finite element analysis to find the resistance of the important paths.

In terms of the overall design, don't forget to also consider:

- Via resistance
- Return path resistance
- Inductive effects (in case you need to switch the current on and off quickly)